# What's the origin of the distinctive noise that Transformers make when they transform?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, transformers, sound-effects

When Transformers in the G1 continuity transform, they make a distinctive five-part noise:
http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformation#The_noise

What's the "behind the scenes" story for that noise... someone who worked on the original cartoon must have invented that sound, but I haven't been able to find the back story online.

Comment: I don't know why you think there's going to be a "back story". It was likely created by a sound engineer and/or foley artist. There's some discussion [here](http://www.tfarchive.com/community/showthread.php?threadid=26548&highlight=sound), and that includes a copy/paste from some old FAQ that I can't find. It discusses what noises were supposedly used to make up the final sound.

Comment: ‘I don't know why you think there's going to be a "back story"’. Because it’s *awesome*?!?!? I feel like whoever devised it should be up there with Delia Derbyshire in the annals of audio history.

Comment: But as awesome as it is, it's very unlikely that there was some big revelatory moment or story. It was probably just some sound engineer/designer combining things and the production company was happy with one of their results.

Comment: I think that tidibit @phantom42 mentioned is probably all that we're going to find. I've been pursuing TF forums for trivia for a long time, and this was the only explanation of the transformation sound I have ever found.

Comment: Some enterprising blogger needs to track the story down.

Comment: there's a backstory for the Millenium Falcon sound and the Hypnotoad sound...why not the Transformers sound?

Comment: @phantom42 A version of the FAQ you referred to resides [here](http://www.corollaperformance.com/other/tf/tffaq6.html).  This FAQ is mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.toys.transformers/cZSan_eWm1o/C3Bn5pmJ6uQJ).

Comment: @phantom42 The FAQ originates from the alt.toys.transformers Usenet group, and [old versions of it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.toys.transformers/5Y5Yx72sWQ8/oSlroXR2XdUJ) can be found in Google's newsgroup archive. From what I can tell, it seems like the FAQ's comments on sound design in the cartoon are based on fan inference, not creator statements. Per the [reference list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.toys.transformers/h2obESmeL7A/Aei_W9cq-tUJ), the quoted statements were made by Kendrick Chua, author of an in-depth fan site about the Transformers cartoon.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I narrowed down the creator of the sound to five individuals, all of whom were sound engineers or foley artists when work began on the original Transformers cartoon in 1984.  Unfortunately, none of them have been interviewed extensively and none have written or spoken in detail about their sound work on the cartoon.  Sorry, but I tried.

Comment: @Praxis, well if you put that in an answer,  it's still the best one here

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Done.

Comment: Part of the reason why "backstories" are exciting is because not everything has one. Most of the time the creative elements you like and remember are just artists doing their job well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Lack of available information

I narrowed down the creator of the sound to eight individuals, all of whom were sound engineers or foley artists when work began in 1984 on the original Transformers cartoon, where the sound first appeared.  They were:

- Jim Blodgett
- Michael L. DePatie
- John Detra
- Ron Fedele
- Michael Tomack
- Richard B. Elliot
- Richard S. Gannon
- Richard C. Allen

(See [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086817/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) for instance.)

Unfortunately, none of them have been interviewed extensively, nor have any of them written or spoken in detail about their sound work on the cartoon.

Unless one of these individuals decides to reveal the "back story" behind the creation of this distinctive sound effect, I doubt that an answer can be found at the present time.

Comment: to the twitterverse??

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Where have you been lately?!  Sure, I might do that. :-)